# Claims-based auth and circles of users

Tags: authentication, authorization, claims-based-identity, jwt

Let's think of a simple REST-based web service to store and retrieve JSON objects. Without any authentication, every user can access any data.

Now let's add usage of JWTs to authenticate users. Of course, since we are not doing authorization, still every user can access anything, but at least now we know who accesses what.

Next step: When storing an object, save the user's `sub` claim with the object, and verify that the user's `sub` claim matches the one of the requested object, and if so, deliver it. Now we have authorization on a per-user basis. So far, so easy.

Now let's add the possibility to let users share objects with other users. For the sake of simplicity, say, we want to have predefined groups (i.e., roles) and we want to let the user choose which group (role) has access to the objects they create. This is still easy, as you have a predefined list of groups, so you can let the user choose one or more, and attach them to the object. Additionally, the identity provider needs to be configured in a way that it put a `groups` claim into every user's token, so we can match them. As we can already see from the length of this paragraph, things become more complex.

Question 1: Am I right so far, that handling "static" groups this way it the way to go?

Now, let's give the users the opportunity to create groups on their own. This is still not complicated, but how do we make the identity provider use the dynamically created groups? For sure we do not want to make an administrator update the identity provider's configuration every day ;-).

Question 2: How do we handle dynamically created groups?

Now, finally, let's forget about groups, and let's say, that we want to allow the users to be able to simply share their objects with other users. This should be configurable for every object individually. How do we do this? Do we save a list of users on the object? If so, what exactly do we save? The `sub` claim? If so, how does the owner user know the appropriate values? Or ...?

And: Supposed the users want to put their friends dynamically into dynamically generated circles, how would we do that?

Question 3: How do tokens and dynamically created groups with dynamically assigned users work with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the tokens should only include identity-information(-claims) you'll need to identify the user on your ressource server or that wont change when refreshing, since you wouldn't want your user (or your app in place) to have to refresh his access tokens each and every time his permissions change (since access tokens grant access for a specific amount of time you wouldn't want your user to have access to certain ressources that he's lost the access rights to since his last token refresh by not refreshing the token and simply using the old one either). The more security related information you append to your token, the more vulnerability you may add to your system (depending on your token lifetime).

Stating so, I would (and always do) identify the users roles or groups by his user-id (which is included in the jwt-token) on the ressource server. To achieve this, I always attach the users identity-information to the current request on my ressource server and attach "dynamic"-claims like the users role or group to the identity.

By adding only the identity information I need to identify the user and the user's rights on my ressource server, I tend to use my identity providers across multiple applications without handling application scope on the identity provider, so I can use the exact same access token for multiple independent ressource servers.